# How to store text, and use for an element search, in Selenium and Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've tried this a few different ways, but I am unable to accomplish what should be straight forward. Here's what I am trying to do as an example:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('foo').text
driver.find_element_by_class_name('foo').click()
if ('text') in driver.find_element_by_class_name('bar')
     print ("Pass")
else:
     print ("Fail")
```

I hope I'm being clear on my intentions. Please feel free to ask for clarifications anywhere. I am looking for dynamic text in one element, and verify it exists in another element.

Now I've tried suggestion:

```
searchText = driver.find_element_by_class_name('foo').text
driver.find_element_by_class_name('foo').click()
text = driver.find_element_by_class_name('bar').text
print (searchText in text)
```

... this does nothing at all. No errors, and no print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close... I think this is what you are looking for. Assign the first element's text to a variable, `searchText`. See if `searchText` is in the text of the next element and then print the result.

```
searchText = driver.find_element_by_class_name('foo').text
print "searchText: " + searchText
text = driver.find_element_by_class_name('bar').text
print "text: " + text
print "found: " + str(searchText in text)
```

This prints `True` if `searchText` is contained in `text`, `False` if it isn't.

Comment: Thanks, @JeffC. Oddly, that returns nothing at all. No error, no terminal print. Nothing.

Comment: Edited the answer... let's debug... I added prints after each find. See what they print.

Comment: getting close, JeffC. Got an error that will help `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'bool' objects`

Comment: Oops... I don't do python... I didn't realize that you couldn't concatenate a string and boolean. I fixed the code above... try now.

Comment: found it .. `print "found: " + str(searchText in text)'